# Monitoring non-Celery background task with New Relic in Python

Tags: python, django, newrelic

I have a web application written with Django. I have several cron jobs which I would like to monitor with New Relic. The new Relic documentation mentions how to monitor Celery-based Python tasks. Unfortunately, I do not use Celery at this time but would like to use New Relic to monitor these tasks as well. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So we can help. what are using?

Comment: I work for New Relic and, yes, there are ways to instrument non-Celery background jobs. It's not documented yet, because the solution is non-obvious and it depends a little on your task. If you file a support ticket, we'd be happy to help you with more info.

Answer (score 4):

Graham Dumpleton from New Relic posted an article on their blog recently detailing how to monitor Django management commands:

https://web.archive.org/web/20161010064354/http://blog.newrelic.com/2014/03/18/monitoring-django-management-commands/

Comment: the link is dead now

Comment: @Rishav I've updated the link